# Using python to fill in one .csv file with data from another .csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have two .csv files, one CSV1 and the other CSV2. In CSV1 is a large list of data formatted like this:

```
name, year
Brian, 2016
Lucy, 2016
Bob, 2014
Alen, 2012
```

Then in CSV2:

```
year, zodiac
2016, Monkey
2015, Goat
2014, Horse
2013, Snake
2012, Dragon
```

I want to make it so in CSV1 the zodiac for each person appears as an additional column like this:

```
name, year, zodiac
Brian, 2016, Monkey
Lucy, 2016, Monkey
Bob, 2014, Horse
Alen, 2012, Dragon
```

I think it is possible to do this with the python Pandas library but I got lost in the documentation - any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A good introduction to pandas would be the [10 Minutes Tutorial](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html). It will give you almost everything you need to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try out [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html). It makes it dead simple:

```
import pandas as pd
# Loads csv1 with default index
df1 = pd.read_csv("csv1.csv")
# Loads csv2 and sets the year as the index
df2 = pd.read_csv("csv2.csv", index_col=0)

df1["zodiac"] = df1["year"].map(df2["zodiac"])

df1.to_csv("output.csv")
```

Note that the index of `df2` is the year - so it essentially behaves in a similar way to a dictionary of year-sign. `map` takes a dictionary or `pandas.Series` as a lookup table to the values in the column.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the [df.join()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) method is exactly what you want! You will be able to join the two dataframes on the year column, and then export it back to csv however you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

fn1 = r'/path/to/file1.csv'
fn2 = r'/path/to/file2.csv'

pd.merge(pd.read_csv(fn1, skipinitialspace=True),
         pd.read_csv(fn2, skipinitialspace=True)) \
  .to_csv('/path/to/result.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Looks like you're paying attention to what the op wanted.

Comment: @piRSquared, thank you! I'm getting a feeling that you never sleep ;-)

Comment: in a cab going back to airport. Not True. I slept for like 3 hours